# Pulling specific part out of Json string with php

Tags: php, mysql, json

i'm trying to log the activity of MtGox using their api, 
they deliver a standard json string http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker

now this is what i use to actually put everything into a neatly organized array

```
$url = 'http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

BUT, then i can't figure out how i can pull specific details like, High>Value.
instead i force myself to go the long way by printing out everything using the following loop:

```
foreach($obj as $arr) {
if (is_array($arr)) {
foreach($arr as $arry) {
if (is_array($arry)) {
            $query_insert_json = "INSERT INTO currency(currency, currentValue, highValue, lowValue) VALUES('USD', '$arry[value]', '12.987', '9.452')";
            $result_insert_json = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_json);
            if (!$result_insert_json) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }   
echo <<<END
<tr>
<td align="center">$arry[value]</td>
<td align="center">$arry[value_int]</td>
<td align="center">$arry[display]</td>
<td align="center">$arry[display_short]</td>
<td align="center">$arry[currency]</td>
</tr>
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? `pull specific details like, High>Value`

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker");
$json=json_decode($json,true);

echo $json['data']['high']['value'];
?>
```

If you want to find which data to pull, view source while `print_r($json)`, then look at it:

[image: array]

Every indentation is another level, looking at the first level, it's `data`, then going to the second it is `high`, then lastly it's `value`.